# C++ Move constructor/Move assignment operator for cyclic dependent objects

Tags: c++, move, move-semantics, circular-dependency

I have the following question regarding the Move constructor/Move assignment operator for two classes *A* and *B*, where one object of *A* is connected to exactly one object of *B* and vice versa.

```
class B;
class A{
public:
    B *ptr_to_B;
};

class B{
public:
    A *ptr_to_A;
};
```

(Code only to illustrate the problem, it is a One-to-One-relationship)
If I now define a move constructor/move assignment operator for *A* and *B*, it is no problem, that eg for *B*, the object I move to (b2), gets the pointer to *A* (a1), and the moved-from object (b1) gets a nullptr. 
But now  I have the problem, that the pointer in *A* (a1) to *B* is pointing to a moved-from object (b1), but I want it to point to the object b2.
Is my circular design flawed? What is the correct design for move semantics in regard to circular dependencies?

Comment: How big are the connected components? If it is just pairs of objects, fix the pointer in the other object. Otherwise, options are to visit all objects in the connected component, or to keep a list of inbound connections in each object (add a data member - a list of objects that reference `this`). (edit: clarification)

Comment: The connected components are not too big; changing the pointer in the other object, and let it point to the moved-to object (eg in the move constructor of A: ptr_to_B->ptr_to_A = this), was my only idea so far, but it seemed very un-elegant for me

Comment: Well, if you're asking how to change your design so that it's unnecessary to change the pointers on move, then the provided info is not enough. But yes, on the second thought, moving objects that are being pointed on seems non-idiomatic. Usually the objects that are being moved are allocated on stack, and it's bad practice for pointers to them to survive past their end of life. It's idiomatic to allocate the objects on heap and hold by `unique_ptr` (or `shared_ptr` if your design is not yet well-understood), and don't move them at all. Maybe what you need is actually a graph structure?

Comment: Write `~A()` and `~B()` first.  Then write the default constructors if they are to exist.  Then write the copy constructor and copy assignment if they are to exist.  Show us those, and then it should be much more clear what your move members should look like.